How can I use the PrimeNG Calendar component in Angular 17?
I'm trying to integrate the PrimeNG Calendar component into my Angular 17 project, but I'm having trouble finding the appropriate steps. Can someone guide me on how to properly use the PrimeNG Calendar component in Angular 17? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I have followed the instructions on the PrimeNG documentation, but I am still unable to make it work.

Hello ! What is your problem ? You have a functional stackblitz attached to each component page in the official documentation, you can fork these stackblitz and start from there to fit your needs.
https://primeng.org/calendar

Ok, so here are the steps :

Make sure the styles of PrimeNg are loaded via styles.scss or in angular.json :

@import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
@import 'primeng/resources/primeng.css';
@import 'primeflex/primeflex.css';
@import 'assets/themes/lara/lara-light/blue/theme.scss';
@import 'assets/themes/mytheme/theme.scss';

/*@import 'assets/themes/material/material-light/compact/indigo/theme.scss';*/


Add BrowserAnimationsModule to you app :

providers: [provideRouter(routes), importProvidersFrom(BrowserAnimationsModule)]


Import the CalendarModule and the FormsModule or ReactiveFormsModule

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, CalendarModule, FormsModule],


Then you simply add your calendar component in your own component :

<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
  <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date"></p-calendar>
</div>

